# Append character to input field when start typing without focus to input on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my code

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', logKey);
function logKey($event) {
  var charCode = $event.keyCode;
  if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 || charCode > 107 || charCode > 219 || charCode > 221) && charCode != 40 && charCode != 32 && charCode != 38 && charCode != 41 && (charCode < 43 || charCode > 46)){
      var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
      inputElement.focus();
      inputElement.value = inputElement.value + $event.key;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

On page load, if the user starts typing the focus is focusing the input but it's not allowing the user to enter the characters typed. As of now, the focus is working but it's not working as expected when the user typing continuously.
Please help me out on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work fine (in Firefox) if you remove `inputElement.focus()`

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to create? Appending the typed character in the `keyup` event will duplicate the input - why would you want to do that?

Comment: @charlietfl - Focus is working fine. But when started typing it's not working as expected.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I don't want duplicated characters.

Comment: So why are you using this logic, when that's all it does...? If you don't want to duplicate the characters, remove this JS event handler entirely.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - If I remove this line `inputElement.value = inputElement.value + $event.key;` first character is not appending.

Comment: I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean, as if you remove the JS then all you have is a basic `<input />` element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - On page load user won't click on the input to focus. The user will start typing without focusing on the element.

Comment: In that case just call `document.getElementById("input").focus()` when the page loads, not in a `keyup` event handler.

Comment: No no, when the user starts typing only I need to focus.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense. I added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the code in the question is because you're appending the character which was just typed in the input back in to the input, effectively duplicating that character.

Given your statement in the comments of your intended goal:

> when the user starts typing only I need to focus on the input

You can attach a `keypress` event handler to the `document` which sets focus on the `input` as soon as a character is typed:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', e => {
  var charCode = e.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 || charCode > 107 || charCode > 219 || charCode > 221) && charCode != 40 && charCode != 32 && charCode != 38 && charCode != 41 && (charCode < 43 || charCode > 46)) {
    $('#input').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

I would also suggest you review your `if` condition, as the 3 conditions following `> 57` are redundant.

```
 charCode > 57 || charCode > 107 || charCode > 219 || charCode > 221
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But can't we achieve this with onKeyUp.?

Comment: No, because keyup fires after the keystroke has occurred, so you lose the value of the first key pressed.

Comment: Perfect. Thank You.

Comment: Can you please suggest code to remove the redundant if logic?

Comment: That would depend on which keys you do/do not want to capture. I'd suggest doing some research on what the keycode are, and starting a new question if you're struggling with it